# What is a good way to check if two or more CGRects touch when they are in a NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimageview, intersection

I have Several UIImageViews in a NSMutableArray. They are all in the superView. I want to check if a UIImageView intersects (collides, hits or touches) another UIImageView in the array. This is what I have been doing but I think there should be a better way.

```
for (UIImageView *b in _blocks) {
    for (UIImageView *b2 in _blocks) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(b2.frame, CGPointMake(b.center.x, b.center.y + b.frame.size.height/2))) {
            // Do something
        }

    }

}
```

If I want to check if the image view is touching more than 2 views this way, the code is going to get very nasty. Thats why I want to know a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
 NSMutableArray *arrIntersect = [NSMutableArray array];
 for (UIImageView *b in _blocks) {
    for (UIImageView *b2 in _blocks) {
         if (b != b2 && CGRectIntersectsRect(b2.frame, b.frame)) {
            if(arrIntersect.count > 2)
               //count > 2
            else
               [arrIntersect addObject:b2];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to prevent the same image to be compared with itself

Comment: This got me going. I am doing something very similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

Use : `CGRectIntersectsRect(b2.frame, b.frame)`

As follows :

```
for (UIImageView *b in _blocks) {
    for (UIImageView *b2 in _blocks) {
         if (b != b2 && CGRectIntersectsRect(b2.frame, b.frame)) {
            // Do something
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to check all the blocks in the second loop. Start from the next block in the array till the end. If block1 doens't intersect with block10. Block10 doesn't have to check block1 again.

Comment: Ok, but your code will check all the blocks for block1. Then check all the blocks again for block2, again all for block3. But block 1 and 3 have already been checked by block1.

Comment: +1 @Thomas My point here was to show the use of CGRectIntersectsRect. I totally agree with the optimization you noted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right approach, however you are duplicating the check, and so it's probably better to check in a single loop:

```
NSInteger count = [_blocks count];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
{
    for (NSInteger j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
    {
        UIImageView *iv1 = [_blocks objectAtIndex:i];
        UIImageView *iv2 = [_blocks objectAtIndex:j];
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(iv1.frame, iv2.frame)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Consider that your original code is checking all objects twice (for example image view 3 and 5 and then 5 and 3 later in the loop).